# The Correct C# PInvoke Signature For This WebP C++ Function

Tags: dll, interop, pinvoke, webp

Im trying to write a C# wrapper for [Google's WebP encoder](http://code.google.com/speed/webp/docs/api.html).

The method im trying to call is:

```
// Returns the size of the compressed data (pointed to by *output), or 0 if
// an error occurred. The compressed data must be released by the caller
// using the call 'free(*output)'.
WEBP_EXTERN(size_t) WebPEncodeRGB(const uint8_t* rgb,
                              int width, int height, int stride,
                              float quality_factor, uint8_t** output);
```

Borrowing from [mc-kay's decoder wrapper](https://github.com/mc-kay/libwebp-sharp/blob/master/libwebp-sharp/Native.WebPDecoder.cs) I have come up with the following:

```
[DllImport("libwebp", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr WebPEncodeRGB(IntPtr data, int width, int height, int stride, float quality, ref IntPtr output);
```

Unfortunately whenever I try to run this I get the following error:

> A call to PInvoke function 'WebPSharpLib!LibwebpSharp.Native.WebPEncoder::WebPEncodeRGB' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I have tried many variations on the signature to no avail.

Anyone got a clue?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Remove the the `ref` on the final `IntPtr` parameter.

Comment: @JaredPar: No, don't.  That's a double-pointer.

Comment: What size are those C++ `int`s?

Comment: @SLaks On Windows C/C++ `int` is 32 bit. In fact so is C/C++ `long`.

Comment: @SLaks a double pointer can be correctly marshalled as an `IntPtr`.  They're the same size and you can dig through the `IntPtr` on the managed side to find the inner value

Comment: @JaredPar: So? A `ref IntPtr` is easier to work with, and is still correct.

Comment: @SLaks when tracking down pinvoke signature failures I always revert the signature to the simplest possible form and work backwards from there.

Comment: @Slaks It depends on what the protocol of the interface is. Knowing the signature is not enough. uint8_t** can be many things. It could be purely an input value although clearly that's not the case here with a name of `output`!

Comment: The return value of the PInvoke version looks wrong, shouldn't it just be an int?

Comment: @Neil No, `size_t` is the same size as a pointer. However, it is an unsigned value and so `UIntPtr` may be more correct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It may be the same size as a pointer, but it doesn't look as if it should be used as if it was one...

Comment: @Neil Can you name another C# type which has the property that it is 32 bits wide in a 32 bit process and 64 bits wide in a 64 bit process? Without such a beast at hand, there's nothing much else to do. Once you get it back you can assign it to a C# `long` and get to work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, I keep forgetting about 64bit. Slap wrists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause for the error is that the C++ code uses `cdecl` calling convention but your pinvoke uses `stdcall` calling convention. Change the pinvoke as follows:

```
[DllImport("libwebp", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern UIntPtr WebPEncodeRGB(IntPtr data, int width, int height, 
    int stride, float quality, ref IntPtr output);
```

There's no need to specify `CharSet` for a function that has no text parameters. I also would use `UIntPtr` as the return type since `size_t` is unsigned.

There may be more problems with your code because we can't see how you are calling the function and we also don't know what the protocol is for calling it. You need to know more than the function signature in order to know how to call a function. However, I suspect that the calling convention problem will get you past your current hurdle.

Comment: That got it! Threw me off because mc-kay didnt have Cdecl on his DllImports